# How to get record with like statement in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have get the record in dynamic created table in .cs page and I know how should I can get the record with specific id as below

```
string searchExpression = "ID = 5"
DataRow[] foundRows = YourDataTable.Select(searchExpression);
```

Now you can loop through the results, like this:

```
foreach(DataRow dr in foundRows)
{

}
```

But I don't know how can I write like statement on .cs page.

**I had tried as below but not working**

```
string searchExpression = "ID like'%5%'"
DataRow[] foundRows = YourDataTable.Select(searchExpression);
```

Comment: `ID` is most likely a numeric field, like `INT` or `BIGINT`. So, most likely, you'll have to convert it to a `VARCHAR` before you can use `LIKE` since `LIKE` operates on character data. So try `Convert(ID, 'System.String') LIKE '%5%'`

Comment: Same rules as for `DataColumn.Expression`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Icemanind can u answer me with example

Comment: @Xtremcool - I did give you an example: `string searchExpression = 
 "Convert(ID, 'System.String') LIKE '%5%'"`

Comment: @Icemanind i tried it like string searchExpression = "Convert(Request#, 'System.String') LIKE '%5%'". But the # sign is giving me issue , my column name is request# so how can I do so

Comment: @Xtremcool - Surround `Request#` with `[` and `]`.

Comment: @Icemanind my last query is I have date like 11/15  and i am passing it as query = query + " or [Requested On] like '" +"#"+ getsearchrecord +"#"+ "'";   dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = query; but giving me as error can u help me out for date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do:

```
string searchExpression = "ID like'*5*'";
```

To make it more reusable, concat it. Like:

```
string searchExpression = "ID like '*" + fromParameter + "*'";
```

I think it throws exception if you search for "*" itself, cant remember properly though. Please test that case.

Please refer to the article at: http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/
on how to write expression for filtering/selecting.

Copied from the link above:

> If a column name contains any of these special characters ~ ( ) # \ / = > < + - * % & | ^ ' " [ ], you must enclose the column name within square brackets [ ]. If a column name contains right bracket ] or backslash \, escape it with backslash (] or \).

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Num = 10"             // number is equal to 10
dataView.RowFilter = "Date < #1/1/2008#"    // date is less than 1/1/2008
dataView.RowFilter = "Name <> 'John'"       // string is not equal to 'John'
dataView.RowFilter = "Id IN (1, 2, 3)"                    // integer values
dataView.RowFilter = "Price IN (1.0, 9.9, 11.5)"          // float values
dataView.RowFilter = "Name IN ('John', 'Jim', 'Tom')"     // string values
dataView.RowFilter = "Date IN (#12/31/2008#, #1/1/2009#)" // date time values
dataView.RowFilter = "Name LIKE 'j*'"       // values that start with 'j'
dataView.RowFilter = "Name LIKE '%jo%'"     // values that contain 'jo'
```

Comment: and what if I have to search for name? string searchExpression = "Name like'*5*'";   it would be same?

Comment: I don't have a code set up to test that on me. I added a link hopefully that will help or you could just give it a try. Although the examples shown in the link are for RowFilter, Select should behave the same.

Comment: I had tried like this  dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Name like '*" + getsearchrecord + "*' or Status like '*" + getsearchrecord + "*'"; an is working but in case of id it is not working, can u help me out

Comment: The column name is case sensitive. Are you sure you've spelled the column exactly the way it is on the table? Do you get any error or it just doesn't filter?

Comment: i tried it like string searchExpression = "Convert(Request#, 'System.String') LIKE '%5%'". But the # sign is giving me issue , my column name is request# so how can I do filter

Comment: Ohhh in that case enclose your column name with []. like [Request#] - case must match.

Comment: I know i had marked u as answer but my last query is I have date like11/15 and i am passing it as  query = query + " or  [Requested On]  like '*" +"#"+ getsearchrecord +"#"+ "*'"; but giving me as error can u help me out for date

Comment: Sure. Whats the error? Where is the year part on your date?

Comment: 11/15/2017 like wise but as i had used like statement it should work for 11/15 too , correct?

Comment: No you can't do that for date datatype. You have to convert the date to string and compare it like a string data type. you have use Convert and then do like. I think that would be a good question to ask, if it already isn't in SO already.